# Proof of a logical theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

> Prove that if for every proposition $\psi\left(p_{0}, \ldots, p_{n}, p\right)$ there exists
> $\phi\left(p_{0}, \ldots, p_{n}\right)$ in which $\psi\left(p_{0}, \ldots, p_{n}, p\right) \rightarrow\left(\phi\left(p_{0}, \ldots, p_{n}\right) \leftrightarrow p\right)$ is a tautology then $\phi$ is a definition of $p$ in terms of $\psi$ then $\left(\psi\left(p_{0}, \ldots, p_{n} , p\right) \wedge \psi\left(p_{0}, \ldots, p_{n}, q\right)\right) \rightarrow(p \leftrightarrow q)$ is a tautology. $p_{0}, \ldots, p_{n}, p , q$ are atoms.

I looked it up in two logic books A Mathematical Introduction to Logic and Logic and Structure but couldn't find this theorem. I'm new to logical proofs and I don't know where to begin in proving this theorem. Is there anyone who can name some books that contain this theorem? If not please explain how this logical proof works.

Comment: Crossposted: [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145012/), [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283962/). [Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain what is going on here by way of an example:
$$
\psi(p_0,p_1,p) = p \leftrightarrow (p_0 \land p_1).
$$
That is, $\psi(p_0,p_1,p)$ is true iff $p = p_0 \land p_1$.

If you define
$$
\phi(p_0,p_1) = p_0 \land p_1,
$$
then we indeed have
$$
\psi(p_0,p_1,p) \to (\phi(p_0,p_1) \leftrightarrow p),
$$
which means that if $\psi(p_0,p_1,p)$ holds then $p = \phi(p_0,p_1)$.

Clearly, in this case, if both $\psi(p_0,p_1,p)$ and $\psi(p_0,p_1,q)$ hold then $p = q$, since both are equal to $\phi(p_0,p_1)$.

---

Now for the formal proof. We assume that
$$ \tag{$\ast$}
\psi(p_0,\ldots,p_n,p) \to (\phi(p_0,\ldots,p_n) \leftrightarrow p),
$$
and want to conclude
$$
(\psi(p_0,\ldots,p_n,p) \land \psi(p_0,\ldots,p_n,q)) \to (p \leftrightarrow q).
$$

Assume, therefore, that $\psi(p_0,\ldots,p_n,p)$ and $\psi(p_0,\ldots,p_n,q)$ both hold. Assumption ($\ast$) implies that
$$ p \leftrightarrow \phi(p_0,\ldots,p_n) \leftrightarrow q, $$
and so $p \leftrightarrow q$.

Answer (score 0):

This problem sounds quite abstract and I'll sketch a proof below. To prove the final material conditional is a tautology, we only need to prove $\psi(p_0, \ldots p_n, p) \wedge \psi(p_0, \ldots p_n, q) \land \lnot (p \leftrightarrow q)$ is unsatisfiable, which means it can never be the case that $p,q$ can have opposite truth values while both $\psi(p_0, \ldots p_n, p)$ and $\psi(p_0, \ldots p_n, q)$ are true. In general cases this obviouly could be satisfied, for example in the case of a disjunctive normal form, $\psi(p_0, \ldots p_n, p)=p_0 \lor \ldots \lor p_n \lor p$.

However, we have the given assumption $\psi(p_0, \ldots p_n, p) \rightarrow (\phi(p_0, \ldots p_n) \leftrightarrow p)$ as a tautology, this obviously blocks the previous case as $\phi$ now must be truth-functionally dependent on $p$, for example, if $\psi=p_0 \land \ldots \land p_n \land \lnot p$, then we can have $\phi=\lnot (p_0 \land \ldots \land p_n)$. This given tautology (premise) thus ensures us that $\phi$ can be thought of as a logically equivalent definition of $p$ in terms of $\psi$ and therefore $p$ must be logically equivalent to $\phi(p_0, \ldots p_n)$ alone (nothing else), as a result it can never be the case that $p,q$ can have opposite truth values while both $\psi(p_0, \ldots p_n, p)$ and $\psi(p_0, \ldots p_n, q)$ are true.